# MODx Revolution неправильный вывод изображения через getImageList

Tags: modx

Использую такую конструкцию для вывода одного изображения:

```
[[!getImageList? 
    &tvname=`nameoftv` 
    &outputSeparator=`` 
    &tpl=`@CODE:<img src="[[+image]]">` 
    &limit=`1` 
    &docid=`[[+id]]`
]]
```

На выходе получаю такое:

```html
<img src="
image/url.jpg">
```

Откуда мог взяться перенос строки?

Answer (score 0):

Проверь само значение `[[+image]]` которое хранится в базе - может быть там перевод строки есть. Больше ему взяться неоткуда.